# Longest common sub sequence recurrence

Tags: dynamic, lcs

The recurrence for `lcs` is:

```
L[i,j] = max(L[i-1,j], L[i,j-1]) if a[i] != a[j]
```

Can you tell me why it is `i-1` or `j-1`? Why isn't `L[i,j] = L[i-1,j-1]` correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are considering the case where `a[i] != a[j]`, which means that the letters you are currently comparing of the two sequences A and B are different. Therefore, the length of the longest common subsequence is one of two things :

1. the longest common subsequence of the current substring of A minus its first character and B, i.e. `L[i-1,j]` ;
2. the longest common subsequence of A and the current substring of B minus its first character, i.e. `L[i,j-1]`.

If `L[i-1,j-1]` were correct, it would mean that the current characters in both A and B do not count, they don’t get a "chance" to be part of the subsequence.

See for example [this explanation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960229.html) (note that it works forward in the sequences instead of backward).

Comment: Awesome. The forward approach sums it up.